# Math Ceiling Function Convert to Float error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following code that's giving me an error... I have no idea why - thoughts?

```
file = r"C:\Users\xxxxx"
xls = xlrd.open_workbook(file, on_demand=True)

def roundup(x):
    return int(math.ceil(x / 10000.0)) * 10000

df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name='Sheet2')
cols = ['Id','Total Cost','Custom']
df = df[cols]
df['Total Cost'] = df['Total Cost'].astype(float)
df['cSum'] = df['Total Cost'].cumsum()
print(roundup(df['cSum']))
```

Error:
    TypeError: cannot convert the series to class 'float'

Comment: Please post the full error with traceback, so we can see where the error is occurring

Comment: `df['cSum']` is a SERIES  and `math.ceil(x / 10000.0)`  wants `x` to be a float... use the appropriate numpy methods to do so